# grouping bins in a tableau histogram

Tags: histogram, tableau-api, bins

I have recently started using Tableau. I got a histogram like this:

[image: histogram]

I want to group the bins after 34000K and make it like "34000k +" as in excel. Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many ways to do this, a simple one may be creating a **group** based on values of your field "Number of Shares Of..".

*Edit:*
First create a calculated field to generate the bins manually. The formula looks like this:

```
INT([Your variable]/[bin])*[bin]
```

Then, on this calculated field create a group. Select the members that you want to group (34000K+), and then click Group. Name it as you want.

Finally, use this created group in the column shelf.

Comment: I did that and created a group "34000k+". Now this group is a dimension and I am getting bar chart instead of histogram. I am trying to figure out how to create a histogram.

Comment: how can I get [bin]?

Comment: I did INT([Number of Shares Offered]/[Number of Shares Offered (bin)])*[Number of Shares Offered (bin)]

Comment: I mean the size of each interval, just a number, in this case may be 2000.